# Register dependencies for module not directly referred by any other module

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to use [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) for dependency resolution in my new project. There are some `Interfaces` defined in a separate class library, which is in turn used by various other libraries.The concrete implementations of the `interfaces` are defined in other projects. The plan is to inject implementations.

Now as implementation projects are not directly referred to by any other project, I have to add a reference to it in web application (or console or any other project that will be entry point) to register dependencies though web application does not directly referring anything from those projects.

My question is that is it right to add reference to concrete implementation projects in web application or is there a cleaner way to manage this? I have tried `Packaging` for simple injector as well, but the libraries not referred by other projects are not loaded and registered.

Comment: @steven thanks. it will be resolved by copying dll to website's bin folder.

Comment: That's not what I would advice. As you can read in my answer on the duplicate, let your startup project assembly (the web app in your case) reference all the other projects. Don't forget that layers are not tiers. The Composition Root is layer on its own.